# Latitude and Longitude distance calculations - Python 3.4.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, latitude-longitude

was looking for a bit of help for my computing coursework, need to make a module to work out the distance between 2 Latlong positions using the Haversine equilibrium. Have this code so far:

```
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians

#Radius_Earth is the radius of the planet, I have taken this as 6373.0 
approximately.
Radius_Earth = 6373.0
#These are the current positions of the boat.
Latitude_Boat = radians(input("Please input the latitude of the boat"))
Longitude_Boat = radians(input("Please input the longitude of the boat"))
Latitude_Destination = radians(input("Please input the latitude of the destination"))
Longitude_Destination = radians(input("Please input the longitude of the destination"))
#This is for working out the distance between the given points
Longitudinal_Distance = Longitude_Destination - Longitude_Boat
Latitudinal_Distance = Latitude_Destination - Latitude_Boat
#This is for working out the Haversine formula.
Haversine_Base = sin(Latitudinal_Distance / 2)**2 + cos(Latitude_Boat) * cos(Longitude_Destination) * sin(Longitudinal_Distance / 2)**2
Haversine_Secondary = 2 * atan2(sqrt(Haversine_Base), sqrt(1 - Haversine_Base))

Distance_Between = Radius_Earth * Haversine_Secondary

print("Result:", distance)
```

According to the thread I found it on this should work, can't find it anymore unfortunately and I can't make it work. I receive the traceback error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\LatLongTest.py", line 6, in <module>
    Latitude_Boat = radians(input("Please input the latitude of the boat"))
TypeError: a float is required
```

Can anyone offer any ideas on how to make this work? (Python 3.4.1)

Comment: `float(input(...))`,  youre passing `radians` a string

Comment: In any event, having the `input()` functions directly inside of `radians()` is poor design -- even if you fix the immediate problem by using `float()`. The basic computation should be its own function which expects floats and returns the floats. The code which *uses* this function should handle the user input and output.

Comment: @JohnColeman Programs using `input()` are beyond repair anyway and should be regarded imperfect learning stuff.

Comment: @Alfe True, but even students first learning the language could start to learn how to separate IO from underlying computation

Comment: You guys are acting all high and mighty.  Do you not learn things from the internet?  In fact, I'm pretty sure we all now learn MORE from the internet, than in school, if so inclined.  Even if this is for a class, he did plenty of work.  It doesn't hurt to ask questions if you get stuck on something.  It hurts more not to.

Answer (score 0):

Cast your input to float, i.e. `float(input(''))`.  That way, even if you enter an integer `123` for example, the result will be `123.0`.  You still need to error handle strings though, FYI.

radians is a math function.

```
import math

var = float(input('enter a number: '))
radians(var)
```